# RxJava - When to use Disposable vs DisposableObservers?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

When would I use a disposable vs a disposable observer? I was always under the assumption that you use a disposable observer and call dispose() when you want to unsubscribe. What's the difference between these two?

Using Disposable

```
Disposable disposable = myObservable.subscribe()
disposable.dispose()
```

Using DisposableObserver

```
    DisposableObserver disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Type type) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
myObservable.subscribe(disposableObserver)
disposableObserver.dispose()
```

Comment: Please read the Javadoc of `DisposableObserver`.

Comment: @akarnokd Did you read my question?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc? It is described there, with an example.

Comment: @akarnokd Okay, I see the documents. Can you explain how that answers my question? Not everyone has a PhD and is maintaining this library. For someone with a PhD, you sure do a terrible job at educating

Comment: I teach by asking people to read and think for themselves first. If you don't understand the javadoc, please explain what is it that you don't understand of it?